# How to convert iterator of chars to String?

Tags: rust

I need something like `.collect()` but which will produce `String` instead of container of `char`s, i.e. I need an inverse of [chars()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.chars). I cannot find anything suitable in the documentation. Of course I can implement such a function myself but I'm sure there must be standard solution to this problem.

I'm using stable Rust.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

`.collect()` is generic in what collection it produces, and it can produce the `String` for you!

```rust
let s = "abc".chars().collect::<String>();
```

The trait [`FromIterator`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.FromIterator.html) determines which elements you can collect into which kind of collection, and among the implementors you can find `String` twice:

```rust
impl FromIterator<char> for String
impl<'a> FromIterator<&'a str> for String
```

Both iterators of `char` and of `&str` can be collected to `String`.

Comment: Right, I was trying to use `collect` but it didn't work. Now I see that this was because I had an iterator of `&char` instead of `char`. I added `map` before `collect` to perform conversion and now it works. Thanks.

Comment: There's a shorthand for that conversion by the way (`&T -> T`), the iterator adaptor `.cloned()`.